# Is this possible for every natural $k \geq2$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

> Is it true that for every natural number $k \geq2$ there exist at least one pair $(q_k,q_k+2$) of consecutive even numbers such that both of them have $k$ different prime factors and $q_k+1$ is prime?

This maybe is a silly question (if there is a trivial answer which I do not see at the moment) and I did not think much about it but I like it and I think that it is good to post it. To clarify (if something is not clear) let us take for example $k=2$. We have an example of two consecutive even numbers with two different prime factors with prime between them. They are $12=2 \cdot 2 \cdot 3$ and $14=2 \cdot 7$ and $13$ is prime.

I welcome also computational effort in finding these pairs for $k=2,3,...$, It would be good to see minimal pairs (pairs with smallest entries). In my example for $k=2$ the minimal pair would be $(10,12)$.

Comment: Note that one of the $k$ prime factors of $q_k$ and $q_k+2$ is always $2$

Comment: @vrugtehagel The numbers can share some prime factors, but both must have the same number of them.

Comment: Exactly $k$ prime factors or at least $k$?

Comment: @kingW3 Exactly.

Comment: One with $k=3$; $q_k=180$, so that $180=2^2\cdot3^2\cdot5$, the middle number, $181$ is prime, and $182=2\cdot7\cdot13$. I think your conjecture is likely to be true, but will probably be hard to prove

Comment: For $k=4$, $q_k=1428$. For $k=5$, $q_k=77140$. For $k=6$, $q_k=3847270$.

Comment: For $k=7$, $q_k=117048930$.

Comment: See [OEIS sequence A088075](https://oeis.org/A088075).

Comment: This sequence matches the primality requirement: http://oeis.org/A088076

Comment: @RobertIsrael It is related but not exactly because 10326137821 is not prime.

Comment: A nice first step would be a proof that this sequence is infinite: http://oeis.org/A063464 Theorem 5 in this paper of Goldston, et al, yields this fact. https://arxiv.org/pdf/0803.2636.pdf